# ObjectForScripting in wxWebView?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, web-control

In .NET WebBrowser Control, there is a Property named "ObjectForScripting". As you call window.external in Javascripts, it calls then the Function in .Net Code.

I'm wondering if this exists also in C++ wxWebView? Or maybe in another C++ GUI Library WebControl..

Comment: If you need to ask then the answer is probably no.  The Winforms browser has a pretty strong implementation for the hosting interfaces.  Search the library code for IDocHostUIHandler, GetExternal() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like this in wxWebView at the moment, just the simple [RunScript](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html#afdfb3b58de7556da67a9dfd29b6b1395) method. However there has been some work on doing this using the Webkit based wxWebView backends, more information is available [here](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14255).

Comment: But maybe in chromiumembedded or other Browser Controls?

Comment: I believe CEF does, see http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration